# How do I link the subquery to the main query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having an issue getting `blast_seconds` to show up as the correct value. In my select subquery I need to get the `blast_seconds` to show up within the same time as in my main Select statement. When the query is executed `Year`, `Month`, `ScheduledSeconds`, `TotalDays` and `Totaltrucks` match up, but `blast_seconds` column shows the same value through out all the months.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT      DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])      AS [Year]
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])     AS [Month]
        ,   SUM(Total)                  AS ScheduledSeconds
        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT([Time]))     AS TotalDays
        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT(Equipment))  AS TotalTrucks
        ,   (
                SELECT      SUM(CASE 
                                    WHEN dbo.reasons.status_id = '298' 
                                        THEN (dbo.by_operator_reasons.seconds) 
                                    ELSE 0 
                                END)        
                FROM        dbo.reasons     
                INNER JOIN  by_operator_reasons 
                ON          dbo.reasons.id = by_operator_reasons.reason_id
                INNER JOIN  equipment
                ON          by_operator_reasons.equipment_id = equipment.id     
                WHERE       reasons.descrip LIKE 'Blast' 
                AND         [Time] BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2012-05-15'
                AND         by_operator_reasons.deleted_at IS NULL
                AND         equipment.type = 'Truck'
            ) AS Blast_Seconds              
FROM        by_equipment_times
WHERE       [Time] BETWEEN '2011-01-01' and '2012-05-15' 
AND         equipment_type  = 'Truck'
GROUP BY    DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])
ORDER BY    DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])      ASC
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])     ASC
```

Here is my current output:

```
Year  Month  SchedSec  Days  TotalTrucks  Blast_Seconds
----  -----  --------  ----  -----------  -------------
2011    1    51340448   31        20      4931156
2011    2    51979509   28        22      4931156
2011    3    58845600   31        22      4931156
2011    4    59121967   30        24      4931156
2011    5    66857271   31        25      4931156
2011    6    67306766   30        28      4931156
2011    7    76976358   31        30      4931156
2011    8    80393145   31        30      4931156
2011    9    75556005   30        30      4931156
2011    10   77741205   31        29      4931156
2011    11   75272400   30        29      4931156
2011    12   77691044   31        29      4931156
2012    1    77683752   31        29      4931156
2012    2    72662400   29        29      4931156
2012    3    77574538   31        29      4931156
2012    4    75172177   30        29      4931156
2012    5    37584000   15        29      4931156
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery is not corelated to main query, that is it does not depend on it. You need to connect it, and I believe that you want to do it using Time column.

```
SELECT      DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])      AS [Year]
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])     AS [Month]
        ,   SUM(Total)                  AS ScheduledSeconds
        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT([Time]))     AS TotalDays
        ,   COUNT(DISTINCT(Equipment))  AS TotalTrucks
        ,   (
                SELECT      SUM(CASE 
                                    WHEN dbo.reasons.status_id = '298' 
                                        THEN (dbo.by_operator_reasons.seconds) 
                                    ELSE 0 
                                END)        
                FROM        dbo.reasons     
                INNER JOIN  by_operator_reasons 
                ON          dbo.reasons.id = by_operator_reasons.reason_id
                INNER JOIN  equipment
                ON          by_operator_reasons.equipment_id = equipment.id     
                WHERE       reasons.descrip LIKE 'Blast' 
                AND         DATEPART(YEAR, [Time]) = DATEPART(YEAR, by_equipment_times.[Time])
                AND         DATEPART(MONTH, [Time]) = DATEPART(MONTH, by_equipment_times.[Time])
                AND         by_operator_reasons.deleted_at IS NULL
                AND         equipment.type = 'Truck'
            ) AS Blast_Seconds              
FROM        by_equipment_times
WHERE       [Time] BETWEEN '2011-01-01' and '2012-05-15' 
AND         equipment_type  = 'Truck'
GROUP BY    DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])
ORDER BY    DATEPART(YEAR, [Time])      ASC
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH, [Time])     ASC
```

If you regularly take more than few months it would probably pay off to convert subquery to derived table, grouping by year/month and outer-joining to main query.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you do not tell the

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.reasons.status_id = '298' 
    then (dbo.by_operator_reasons.seconds) ELSE 0 END....
```

sub query to get values for respective rows - it just sums everything it finds. 
You have to bind sub query to main query - something like

```
[...]
    AND equipment.equipemnt_id_or_something = T1.equipment_id_or_something
    ) AS Blast_Seconds              
FROM        by_equipment_times as T1
[...]
```

Or so I think .... :)

PS. 
Names of fields are imaginary.